# Stack overflow in Prolog

Tags: scope, prolog, stack-overflow, parent, nested-lists

I am trying to write Prolog code to determine whether the bound variable `X` is in the scope of the bound variable `Y` in a list. Lists may be nested and `X` is in the scope of `Y` if `X` and `Y` are members of the same list or if `X` is a member of a list that is a member of a list that is a member of a list...(nested indefinitely) that is in the same list as `Y`. Here I define `in_scope(X,Y,List)` to mean that `X` is in the scope of `Y` in the outermost list `List`. I have written the following code, but this code results in  a stack overflow:

```
in_scope(X,Y,List) :- in(Parent,List), member(X,Parent), member(Y,Parent).
in_scope(X,Y,List) :- in(X,Parent), in_scope(Parent,Y,List).

in(X,Y) :- member(X,Y).
in(X,Y) :- member(X,Z), in(Z,Y).
```

I would appreciate help in modifying the code to avoid the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too lazy to trace the actual error, but the following, simplified code

```
in_scope(X,Y,List) :- member(Y,List), in(X,List).
in_scope(X,Y,List) :- member(Sub,List), in_scope(X,Y,Sub).

in(X,List) :- member(X,List).
in(X,List) :- member(Sub,List), in(X,Sub).
```

gives the intended results:

```
?- in_scope(x,z,[x,y,z]).
true .

?- in_scope(x,z,[[x,y],z]).
true .

?- in_scope(x,z,[[[[[x],y]],z]]).
true .

?- in_scope(x,a,[[[[[x],y]],z]]).
false.
```

But note the following; I'm not sure if this is intended behavior:

```
?- in_scope(x,x,[x]).
true .
```

Comment: Thank you! And should `in_sublist(X,Sub)` be `in(X,Sub)`?

Comment: Yes, apologies. I had renamed the predicate, then renamed it back.

Comment: You're welcome. I did find at least one bug in the `in/2` predicate. Changing the variable names to something intelligible helped a lot there :)